# I have an app (which is not an gaming app ) and now I want to put an effect of stars moving up with score points

Tags: android, animation

I recently came across Android Animation Interpolater and it quite works for me .
But other than that
--what is the way to do it, or is there a library for the same purpose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this library...
very small and simple to use.
https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids